# is this approach thread safe

Tags: c#, multithreading, concurrentdictionary

Is approach below thread safe? I know ConcurrentDictionary provides TryRemove method but I just don't like to have a variable for value that I never gonna use.

```
ConcurrentDictionary<int, int> myDict = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, int>();

if (myDict.ContainsKey(1))
    ((IDictionary<int, int>)myDict).Remove(1);
```

Comment: TryRemove is exposed for a reason.

Comment: That is a silly argument.  TryRemove is the safest way to access your data.  You will get a return of True/False from it which let's you know if you should process the out variable.

Comment: If you really don't like having the variable laying around after TryRemove, then just scope it so it is only valid for that call.

Comment: @Katie That's possible, but fairly cumbersome in C#.

Comment: Why do you ignoring value stored in dictionary? If answer is "I already read it.", then very likely that your code is not thread safe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your aim seems to be to improve code clarity by removing the need to use an `out` parameter. That is a valid concern but using `Remove` is not the right way to go.

Define yourself a helper method:

```
static bool TryRemove<TKey, Value>(
      this ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, Value> dict, TKey key) {
 TValue value;
 return dict.TryRemove(key, out value);
}
```

Comment: like it better than what CLR giving me

Comment: @Servy yeah i mean .NET